# Foreign key is not supported in existing database

Tags: android, sqlite

Dummy application :i created a sqlite database with 20 tables and foreign key functonality is enabled (`"PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON"`).this database is used for another application through Assests folder,and my question is foreign key is not supported.

ex. `CREATE TABLE Student(Studend_id Integer not null,student_name String, FOREIGN KEY ((Studend_id ) REFERENCES Dept(Deptid));`

```
CREATE TABLE Dept(Deptid Integer not null,dept_name String)
```

Dept table data is

```
Deptid   dept_name
500      cse
400      ece
```

In dummy application i try add the column in student it throws exception foreign key is mis mashed

```
insert into student(300,"sri");
```

same query i try to executed in my application it doesn't throw any exception and column is added here foreign key is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

In your case Student table references deptid column of Dept table. As you can see you Dept table's deptid column has not got a value 300.

```
Deptid   dept_name
500      cse
400      ece
```

As there is no value 300 in dept table you cannot insert a new record. Your student table is dependent of Dept table for values. If you

```
Deptid   dept_name
500      cse
400      ece
300      eee
```

then it would have worked. By this I mean you cannot create a value in student table that is not present in Dept table. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes,but my doubt is i created the database in one application and this database used to another application.

Comment: @sri May be your other application might had that value. Please check that once. The error you are getting is because of the reason I said. I recommend you to check the database of both the application and check for existing values.

Answer (score 0):

`PRAGMA foreign_keys` works only for the current connection.

You cannot enable foreign keys for another application that you do not control.